# explorer.exe Window Steals Focus

Tags: windows-explorer, tasks, window-focus

I've been having intermittent problems with a window stealing focus in Windows 10 Professional.  I ran Windows Focus Logger (by Adminscope) and it indicates the `Process_name` stealing the focus is `explorer` with a `Mainwindow_title` of `Task Switching`.  It is very annoying, especially when I'm in a full-screen application and it pulls me out.  Obviously, I can't stop using `explorer.exe`.

Thanks.

As requested, I've attached a logfile containing the list of modules in `explorer.exe` at http://www.ikickass.org/logs/log.txt .

Comment: Could be a module loaded into Explorer.  Maybe attach the output of the following PS command: `Get-Process explorer | select path, modules | % {$(get-filehash -ea silentlycontinue $_.Modules.Filename)}`  Ensure the PS window is wide enough to get the full path.  Could send the data to a file with a `> log.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your kind attention.  I've attached a link to the logfile.